# What is the difference between `go install`, `govendor install +local` and `govendor install +vendor,^program`?

Tags: go, govendor

When using govendor, what is the difference between `go install`, `govendor install +local` and `govendor install +vendor,^program`?

`govendor install +vendor,^program` says to build and install all my vendor packages. but what and where will it install to? Will it install my project and vendor's command executables to `$GOPATH/bin` and my project and vendor's package objects to `$GOPATH/pkg`?

`govendor install +local` says to build everything in your repository only. So what does it really mean? Will it create `vendor/bin` and `vendor/pkg`?

what about if I run `go install` in my project? What will this be different to the above two commands?

Answer (score 0):

Go first came into the world with a brand new idea for dependency management and workspace folder structure. There was a strict hierarchy where projects would be located (in `$gopath/src/site.com/user/project`) and other projects would simply import the latest version of all other projects. The problem with this is that if some upstream project changes the API, then your project will break inexplicably. This is where vendor comes in.

Vendor is a subdirectory in your project that contains everything under `$gopath/src` that your project imports. The difference is that vendor isn't updated when upstream projects introduce new features and/or fixes. Therefore, you must update it yourself. When go looks for an import (as of the latest version), it will check vendor first and then look for the latest version in your `$gopath`, preventing builds from inexplicably breaking for no apparent reason.

`go install` updates your `$gopath` dependencies to the latest version; the version that all new projects and those without vendor will use.

`govendor install +vendor,^program` updates your specific project vendor dependencies. This should be done in a separate commit; you should `go test; govendor; git commit; go test` so that you can check whether updates break your project.

`govendor install +local` apparently just builds the project.

Also, you should IMHO use godep rather than govendor. It IHMO has better workflow; your `$gopath` has the latest versions and then you can update your project with `godep update`. It is also supposed to be standard in golang 1.10.

Comment: Yes, use `godep`.

Comment: (1) Why will it update $GOPATH dependencies when I run `go install <myproject>` if my govendor project has nothing to do with $GOPATH?  
(2) will `go install` and `govendor install +vendor,^program` build the project? You didn't mention it.
(3) if `govendor install +vendor,^program` and `govendor install +local` will build the project, what dir will it build to? what directory will `go install <govendor project>` build to? 
(4) I am using `gin` which switches from godep to govendor. That's why I am using govendor. If godep will become standard in golang 1.10, why does gin drop it? thanks

Comment: @eduncan911 I am using `gin` which switches from `godep` to `govendor`. That's why I am using `govendor`. If `godep` will become standard in golang 1.10, why does `gin` drop it and use `govendor` instead? thanks.

Comment: `go install` simply installs and updates dependencies in your `$GOPATH`. It is simply a global cache of the latest versions available.

Comment: You can still use godep with your own project. Just run go get x && cd proj_dir && godep save

Comment: @xaav just one more question. You said "godep will be standard in golang 1.10". Is this true? Where can I find such announcement/news? I thought govender would become standard in the future. thanks a lot.

Comment: It's pretty obvious considering that govendor has 439 commits and godep has 2024, and in addition, godep is under the official "golang" organization, and the wiki page on github states that fact.